# How can I find the inverse of $y = \frac{x}{1-x^2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse-function

In example $1.5$ of *Cracking the GRE Subject Test*, the authors make the following calculation in one step with no additional commentary:

> we interchange $x$ and $y$ and solve for $y$:
> \begin{align}
> \vdots\\
> xy^2 + y-x &= 0\\
> y &= \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1+4x^2}}{2x}
> \end{align}

What technique allows such a breezy solution?

Comment: What part of the solution does not make sense to you? Interchanging the $x$ and $y$'s, the algebraic manipulation...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the quadratic formula for $ay^2 + by +c = 0$

$$y = \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

Here $a = x$, $b = 1$, $c = -1$

Answer (score 0):

$$y = \frac{x}{1-x^2}$$

Replace $x$ with $y$

$$x = \frac{y}{1-y^2}$$

and solve $y,x=\frac{y}{1-y^2}$

$$-\frac{1\pm\sqrt{4x^2+1}}{2x}$$